# 'Undefined property' in Class, although property is defined

Tags: php, class

I have a PHP function that allows the registration of questions for an FAQ section.  The idea is to allow for the addition of questions along with the content they cover, rather than having to bundle them all in one place.

```
global $faq;
$faq = new ABB_FAQ();

function abb_register_question($id, $title, $callback){

    global $faq;

    $faq->questions[$id] = array(
        'id'        => $id,
        'title'     => $title,
        'callback'  => $callback
    );

}
```

To display the FAQ I simply call the below function.  The `$for_readme` parameter is a switch that tells the code whether or not to format the question for the readme file -

```
function abb_do_faq($for_readme = false){

    global $faq;

    $faq->do_faq($for_readme);

}
```

Now we're inside the `ABB_FAQ` object that will do the rest of the work.  As you can see below, the very first thing that `ABB_FAQ::do_faq()` does is set the `$for_readme` property.  However, when I load the page I'm met with the following notice -

> Undefined property: ABB_FAQ::$for_readme in XXX

I suspect that this is happening because the **callback** function that I pass to `abb_register_question()` contains calls to methods within the `ABB_FAQ` class, and the callback was registered *before* I set ABB_FAQ::$for_readme.

So my question is twofold; is my assumption as to why this is occurring correct, and if so, what can I do about it?

```
public function do_faq($for_readme = false){

    $this->for_readme = $for_readme;

    if(!empty($this->questions)) : foreach($this->questions as $question):
            echo $this->get_question($question);
        endforeach;
    endif;

}

function get_question($question){

    $title = $this->get_question_title();
    $content = call_user_func_array($question['callback'], array($question['id']));

    return $title . $content;

}
```

Comment: Does your class have an instance property named `$for_readme`?

Comment: No, but if I add one all that happens is the notice disappears; the value is still not passed through to the methods that my callback calls. Thanks.

Comment: The question is not very clear. Your title says *'Undefined property' is Class, although property is defined*, what property did you define? And the comment says *value is still not passed through*, what do you mean by this? Are you getting any error?

Comment: For now, I've removed all references to `ABB_FAQ::$for_readme` from methods called by the callback, and I'm instead passing the value as a function parameter.  It's not as "clean cut" as using a class property, but perhaps more appropriate in this instance.